# what is the right regex pattern in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Not so strong yet in groovy regex. I am trying to create a matcher in groovy, for the the string `[sf:retrieve] Request ID for the current retrieve task: 09Sg00000052ZAPEA2`

The last part after the `:` i.e `09Sg00000052ZAPEA2` is the only thing that keeps changing. And how do i get the `09Sg00000052ZAPEA2` part only, if the string is available?

This is what i have tried so far:

```
import hudson.model.*
def parser() {
    def matcher = manager.getLogMatcher(".*Request ID for the*.*")
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        pbn=matcher.group(matcher.groupCount())
        return pbn
    }
}
```

The method doesn't throw any error neither return anything

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.*:\\s(\\w+)` as a pattern and get the first match in group (I've tested with java.util.regex.Pattern), I suppose the lib you are using will do it the same way:

```
String s = "[sf:retrieve] Request ID for the current retrieve task: 09Sg00000052ZAPEA2";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*:\\s(\\w+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of your example is jenkins-specific, and I don't have that available to test, so this answer is plain-old-groovy.  But, this works as I believe you would want:

```
​String toMatch = "[sf:retrieve] Request ID for the current retrieve task: 09Sg00000052ZAPEA2"

def finder = (toMatch =~ /.*Request ID for the current retrieve task:(.*)/)
println finder.matches()
println finder.group(1)
```

Basically, put the part you want to get back in parentheses.  That makes it a numbered group, per Java regex syntax.  You can then use the pattern matcher to get that group value, if it matches.  FYI, group 0 is the full matching string (for the whole regular expression), so you start counting at 1, assuming you don't want the full thing.

When I run this example, I get the output:

```
true
09Sg00000052ZAPEA2
```